# iPhone 4 doesn't load retina images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiimage, retina-display

I have an app for iPhone that uses some images compatible with retina and non retina devices. When I lunch the app on any iPhone simulator it works perfectly, retina and non retina images are loaded.

The issues appear when I select the app to run on my physical device (**iPhone 4**). In this case the retina images are not loaded any more and everything seems blurry.

I used "Don't  Code Sign" since I don't have a developer account **yet**. I just wanted to get a feeling of my app, could it be because of this?

Here is a **sample project** that has the same behaviour on my physical device:
http://db.tt/XL4DPLH8

**Solved:** retina images were name 2X instead of 2x...also in the **project** and in the **example.app** / Thanks for the answer Adam (his answer disappeared)

Comment: Did you name your images properly??? Ex: myimage.png for normal screen and myimage@2x.png for retina screen.

Comment: There're no image for photo_02.png .... where is photo_02@2x.png ?

Comment: retina images were name 2X instead of 2x...also in the project and in the example.app / Thanks for the answer Adam (his answer disappeared)

Comment: Have the retina images been put to the device at all? Create an archive (ipa) and check it out (it's just a zip file).

Answer (score 0):

Check resolution at start up by NSLog and then setting appropriate image...

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
 [super viewDidLoad];

 //   NSLog(@"bound :%f", [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);
 NSString* imageName;
 if([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height == 568)
 {
    imageName= @"568h@2x.png";
 }
 else{
     imageName= @"bg@2x.png";  
 }
 self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage  imageNamed:imageName]];
```

hope help